# Create a <p> tag dynamically

Tags: javascript, html, dom

How can I add a *p* tag in between id=p1 and id=p3 when I click the button "Add P2"?

Here is the code I have so far.

```js
function addParagraphs()
{
    var p2 = "<p>paragraph 2</p>";
    document.getElementsById("p1").appendChild(p2);
}
```

```html
<p id ="p1" > paragraph 1</p>
<p id ="p3" > paragraph 3</p>
<p id ="p4" > paragraph 4</p>
<input id="b2" type='button' onclick='addParagraphs()' value='Add P2'/>
```

Comment: `appendChild` accepts a **DOM element**, not a string.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The simplest solution is to use the [`insertAdjacentHTML`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/insertAdjacentHTML) method which is very convenient for manipulations with HTML strings:

```js
function addParagraphs() {
    var p2 = "<p>paragraph 2</p>";
    document.getElementById("p3").insertAdjacentHTML('beforebegin', p2);
}
```

```html
<p id="p1">paragraph 1</p>
<p id="p3">paragraph 3</p>
<p id="p4">paragraph 4</p>
<input id="b2" type='button' onclick='addParagraphs()' value='Add P2' />
```

Another option is to use the [`insertBefore`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/insertBefore) method, but it's a bit more verbose:

```js
function addParagraphs() {
    var p2 = document.createElement('p');
    p2.innerHTML = 'paragraph 2';
    var p3 = document.getElementById("p3");
    p3.parentNode.insertBefore(p2, p3);
}
```

```html
<p id="p1">paragraph 1</p>
<p id="p3">paragraph 3</p>
<p id="p4">paragraph 4</p>
<input id="b2" type='button' onclick='addParagraphs()' value='Add P2' />
```

Answer (score 6):

You have a typo. It's `getElementById`, not `getElementsById`. Only one single element can be gotten with a certain ID.

And you should be using `createElement` and insertBefore to insert the element between the two other elements, `appendChild` appends ***to*** the element.

```js
function addParagraphs() {

    var p2 = document.createElement('p');

    p2.innerHTML = "paragraph 2";

    var elem = document.getElementById("p1");

    elem.parentNode.insertBefore(p2, elem.nextSibling);

}
```

```html
<p id ="p1" > paragraph 1</p>
<p id ="p3" > paragraph 3</p>
<p id ="p4" > paragraph 4</p>
<input id="b2" type='button' onclick='addParagraphs()' value='Add P2'/>
```

Answer (score 3):

A simple jQuery solution would be to use `.insertAfter`:

```
function addParagraphs() {
    var p2 = "<p>paragraph 2</p>";
    $(p2).insertAfter("#p1");
}
```

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/quyytat6/3/)

Answer (score 2):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head lang="en">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title></title>
</head>

<html>
    <body>
        <script>
            function addParagraphs()
            {
                var para = document.createElement("p");
                var node = document.createTextNode("paragraph 2");
                para.appendChild(node);
                var element = document.getElementById("p2");
                element.appendChild(para);
            }
        </script>

        <p id="p1"> paragraph 1</p>
        <p id="p2"> </p>
        <p id="p3"> paragraph 3</p>
        <p id="p4"> paragraph 4</p>
        <input id="b2" type='button' onclick='addParagraphs()' value='Add P2'/>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Code without an explanation is often not very useful.

Answer (score -3):

```
function addPtag(){
    var x = document.createElement("p");
    var y = document.createTextNode("paragraph content");
    x.appendChild(y);
    document.body.appendchild(x);
}
```

Comment: Please take a look at [How do I write a good answer?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). Posting an answer with only code without explaning how this code will solve the OP's will not help OP. Also your answer is not completely related to OP's question since he wants to insert the created element in a certain place of DOM not at the end of the body...